# How do I add colour to text in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, colors, python-idle

I'm trying to turn certain letters in a word a different colour, and the word as a whole.

I've tried using termcolor and ANSI escape codes and they don't work.

I'm using IDLE as my IDE and Python 3 so this could be the reason? Does anyone have any solutions that work for these conditions?

Comment: ANSI escape sequences only work if the code is run in a terminal, like CMD on Windows. IDLE is not a terminal, which is why they don't work.

Comment: Looks like there is a few great answers in this thread:: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/how-do-i-print-colored-text-to-the-terminal

Answer (score 2):

> I'm using IDLE as my IDE and Python 3 so this could be the reason? Does anyone have any solutions that work for these conditions?

Yes, this is the reason. ANSI escape sequences only work on terminals, eg: CMD, Powershell, etc. Run your code using `python3 file.py` in the terminal and ANSI should work properly.